# Selecting elements following a selected element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am creating a custom accordion menu using jQuery.

[image]

What I want to accomplish is this: 
If a ul within a ul  (for example line 39 in the image) is set to display...
I want to change all of the ul tagged elements FOLLOWING, within the specified div, to no display

Having no luck with .next() or .nextAll()

Code example

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
  <ul class="a-menu">
    <li>
        Main menu 1
        <ul>
            <li>Sub 1 menu 1</li>
            <li>Sub 1 menu 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Main menu 2
        <ul>
            <li>
                Sub 2 menu 1
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub 3 menu 1</li>
                    <li>Sub 3 menu 2</li>
                    <li>Sub 3 menu 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
              Sub 3 menu 2
              <ul>
                <li> Sub 3 menu 1</li>
                <li> Sub 3 menu 2</li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li>Sub 3 menu 3 </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      Main menu 3
      <ul>
        <li>Sub 1 menu 1</li>
        <li>Sub 1 menu 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: nice screenshot btw.. :)

Comment: How do you set the `ul` element to display? Do you click a button? In your example do you mean `ul` line 48 would show too?

Comment: @FelixKling - it says right in the question, it's anything inside the DIV, wherever that is ?

Comment: @adeneo: Obviously I can't read.

Comment: The use of the DIV in this example was done as a mechanism to limit the scope of EVERYTHING after... "Every element after" means exactly that... In this case, every UL and everything contained with in them. I don't think how the child elements got changed to display is relevant. But if it is, they are changed to display via jQuery in response to click (or perhaps mouseover).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

**jQuery**

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('li').click(function(ev) {
      $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle();
      ev.stopPropagation();
      $(this).nextAll("li").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```